# How to write sql query for this:

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

```
mysql> select * from table3 order by id;
+------+-------+
| id   | value |
+------+-------+
|    1 | a     |
|    1 | b     |
|    1 | c     |
|    1 | d     |
|    2 | a     |
|    2 | b     |
|    3 | a     |
|    3 | b     |
|    3 | c     |
|    4 | a     |
|    4 | b     |
+------+-------+
```

I wanted to **select all ids that don't have a value 'c'**.

It will not simply work by following query:

```
mysql> select distinct id from table3 where value <> 'c';
+------+
| id   |
+------+
|    1 |
|    2 |
|    3 |
|    4 |
+------+
```

All I need is **only 2 and 4** return.

Thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select distinct id 
from table3 t
where not exists 
                 (select 1 from table3 where value = 'c' and id = t.id)
```

Answer (score 2):

this will work for you

```
select distinct id from table3 where 
             id not in ( select id from table3 where value = 'c')
```

Comment: Yes, The actual table has more than 10, 000, 000 rows, I will mark your answer later if not find more suitable one, thank you